# Can not access my mysql databases when I use show databases in command line in windows

Tags: mysql, cmd

Hi I am trying to access my database from the cmd in windows. when I go type show databases. It shows me only two of them information_schema and test. I dont know why but the databases exist when I got to localhost/phpmyadmin . Also I have never created any username and password before for it. I used to type mysql -u root to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to grant privileges for the user, including the IP Address from which you access. Do this as mysql root user or user with grant privilege:

**Grant privilege from any IP:**

```
GRANT ALL ON my_database.* TO 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

**Privilege for specific IP:**

```
GRANT ALL ON my_database.* TO 'user_name'@'particular_ip_address' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

For granting access from `localhost`, run the query with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`.